# How to Create Checkbox in Header of Webgrid i can't create Checkbox in header of Web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web, webgrid

i have create one Webgrid which used to display the data into Tabular form but i want to add the checkbox in Header part of webgrid by using this checkbox i want to perorm the operation check all other checkbox into webgrid and perform the ACTIVE And Delete operation..so please help me how to create it ..below my code of Webgrid:

```
<div id="mygrid">
     @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridTable",
         headerStyle: "gridHead",
         footerStyle: "gridFooter",
         rowStyle: "gridRow",
         alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
         columns: grid.Columns(
             grid.Column(header: "",format: @<text><input type="checkbox" name="chkactive[]" value="@item.User_id" /></text>),
             grid.Column("User_Id"),
             grid.Column("Name"),
             grid.Column("Username"),
             grid.Column("Fb_Id"),
             grid.Column("User_image", format: @<text><img src="@Url.Content(@item.Image_path)" height="30px" width="50px" alt="noimage"/></text>),
             grid.Column("Email"),
             grid.Column("Gender"),
             grid.Column(header: "Status", format: @<text>
             @if (@item.Is_active == true)
             { 
                 <a href="@Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/Active.png"/></a> 
             }
             else
             { 
                 <a href="@Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/Deactive.png"/></a> }</text>),
             grid.Column(header: "Edit",
                 format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("EditeUser", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/icons/editor.png" /></a></text>),
             grid.Column(header: "Delete",
                 format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/icons/trash.png"/></a></text>)))
</div>
```

please give me some format to display checkbox into Header ..
when i create checkbox in to header error is display which is best overloaded metho....?
and we also know that header is accept only string type data not to any element..! please give me hint to perform to this operation ok..it;s argent..?

Answer (score 6):

The `WebGrid` helper doesn't support adding markup to a column header. You could use more advanced controls such as [`Telerik MVC Grid`](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid) or [`MVCContrib Grid`](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) which allow this kind of customization.

If you want to use the WebGrid helper you could use javascript to inject the checkbox into the header. It's an ugly hack, but the only one since the helper doesn't support rendering the correct markup.

Here's an example of how that could be done with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.gridTable thead tr th:first').html(
        $('<input/>', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            click: function () {
                var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]');
                checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{    
var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
var columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();

WebGridColumn checkBoxColumn = grid.Column(header: "{}",
   format: (item) =>
   {
       // I need access to item properties, otherwise this can be simplified    
       return Html.CheckBox("send-checkbox", false, new { @class = "singleCheckBox" });
   });
columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
}    

string html = grid.GetHtml(columns: columns).ToString();
 @MvcHtmlString.Create(@html.Replace("{}", "<input type='checkbox' id='allCheckBox'/>"));
}        

<script>
    $().ready(function () {
    $('#allCheckBox').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('.singleCheckBox').prop('checked', isChecked);            
    });

    $('.singleCheckBox').click(function () {
     var allChecked = ($('.singleCheckBox:checked').length == $('.singleCheckBox').length);            
      $('#allCheckBox').prop('checked', allChecked);                        
     });
});
</script>
```

I borrowed some ideas from 
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/13/webgrid-helper-with-check-all-checkboxes.aspx